# start android activity through phonegap plugin

Tags: android, cordova, augmented-reality, phonegap-plugins

I want to create an `AugmentedReality phonegap plugin` on android. I have the `AugmentedReality` source code on android. I would like to launch this android application using the `push button` on `phonegap` application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so you need to [write a plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) in order to start the AR code. Basically you'll write a JS file to call your Java code. In your Java code you will extend the Plugin class from the PhoneGap API and to start your AR code you will fire an intent. Examples of this include:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/BarcodeScanner/2.0.0/src/com/phonegap/plugins/barcodescanner/BarcodeScanner.java
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/ContactView/ContactView.java

There is already one AR plugin for Android:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/AugmentedReality-Wikitude